# List comprehension and copies of types

Tags: python, memory, list-comprehension

I am often tempted *not* to create a new list when using list comprehensions, because if the list is huge, it would mean more space needed to compute (the way I understand it the list is not bieng aliased int his case, a new memory space is created for the new list)

As an illustrative example (this could be done in one line):

```
def average_list(lst):
    lst = [x for x in lst if x > 0]
    return np.average(lst)
```

Is it dangerous to use lst in this way, both in right and left part of the assignment? If so, what situations would cause a problem by reusing lst?

If so why is this "safer"?

```
def average_list(lst):
    clean_lst = [x for x in lst if x > 0]
    return np.average(clean_lst )
```

Comment: There could be confusion if you wanted access to the original lst later. It really just depends on if you need the original list for anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def average_list(lst):
    lst = [x for x in lst if x > 0]
    return np.average(lst)

caller_list = [1,4,-5]
average_list(caller_list)
# caller_list is unchanged
```

here you're reusing the `lst` name only in the function, but you're not changing `lst` in the caller context (and garbage collection doesn't work since the caller still holds a reference on the data)

So reassigning a variable name is perfectly safe but sometimes considered as bad practice because one should not change the values or references of passed arguments.

Note: in the case of `list` a way to change the data itself (which would surprise your function users so don't do it) would be (only applies to lists & more generally *mutable* objects)

```
    lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x > 0]
```

With this slice assignment, the name isn't reused, the object itself is reused & modified. The original contents of the list is replaced by the new contents, here shrunk as there is less data in the new, filtered version. It's cool on local & global variables, but should be avoided in lists passed as parameters (like `append`, `pop` should be avoided too in the general case, always to follow the principle of least astonishment)

Comment: Clarity: The [:] implies lst and caller list share the same memory space and both aliases will be modified

Comment: @dirtyw0lf with this slice assignment, the name isn't reused. The original contents o the list is replaced by the new contents, here shrunk as there is less data in the new, filtered version

Answer (score 1):

There's no danger in reusing `lst` as long as its original value is longer needed, and reusing it does indeed save memory since the original `lst` will lose its reference and get recycled by garbage collection.

Comment: Some people feel that "reusing" the variable in this way is "unclean", but I agree with you. There's no technical issue or problem here.

Comment: The original list referred to by `lst` will only get garbage-collected if there are no other references to it, so this is not always true

Comment: "the original lst will lose its reference and get recycled by garbage collection": not true unless (maybe) the argument is a literal list. Else, caller still holds the original list as reference (just saw MoxieBall comment)

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the original list is absolutely fine, as long as you don't need the original list values.

Comment: it's not reusing the original list, it's reusing the original list _name_